# If a cell value is TRUE then retrieve another cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets I have a formula in Column V that returns "Paid" or "To Pay" depending on whether a checkbox in Column U is checked:

```
=IF(U2=True, "Paid", "To Pay")
```

###### My data looks like this:

|  | T | U | V | W |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Price** | **Checkbox** | **Status** | **Amount** |
| 2 | 80 | ☑ | Paid |  |
| 3 | 80 | ☐ | Not Paid |  |

I want to place a formula in Column W that returns the **Price** value from Column T if the **Checkbox** in Column U is checked.

###### The result would be:

|  | T | U | V | W |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Price** | **Checkbox** | **Status** | **Amount** |
| 2 | 80 | ☑ | Paid | 80 |
| 3 | 80 | ☐ | Not Paid |  |

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

**paste this in cell W2: `=IF(U2=TRUE, T2, )`**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

## TRUE=TRUE

A checkbox value is always TRUE/FALSE (checked/unchecked) therefore it is redundant to test whether it is TRUE.

###### Example:

```
=IF(TRUE, val_if_true, val_if_false)
```

is equivalent to

```
=IF(TRUE=TRUE, val_if_true, val_if_false)
```

## Basic Formula

If you are returning the two columns based on the same test `U2=TRUE` you can use a single formula to generate both columns:

```
=IF(U2, {"Paid", T2}, "To Pay")
```

[image]

## Multi-Row Formula

You can use adapt the Basic Formula using the ARRAYFORMULA function to populate all the values in Columns V and W:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(T2:T,
     IF(U2:U,
       {IFERROR(U2:U/0,"Paid"), T2:T},
       {"To Pay",""}),))
```

[image]